# Is is possible to join FB group / Invite Friends using api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on facebook api using php. I did a functionality to get the search feature in facebook (i.e) by user, group, etc.

Now i am in need to invite the search result user and join that search result group.

I tried more in google but i am not getting any source to join a group.. Is it possible to do that using facebook api?

Please help me on this..

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can send invites to the users to join a group. Here's the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/members/#publish).

But the condition is that:

> An app access token can invite any app users to a group created by that app.

The request must be made with an [**app access token**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/) and this same app must have **created** that group. So, you cannot send request to the friends if that group was not created using an app.

**Edit:**

If you are asking that a user can join the group with Graph API, it's (of course) **not** possible!

Comment: I am asking about joining group and not sending invitation for our group.

Comment: No that's not possible, to avoid spamming I guess

Comment: If the answer is mis-leading or spam; yes of course you can downvote it.